# Chrome extension - Too many images - This extension may have been corrupted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a twitch.tv  extension that increases the amount of usable emotes.

I made an emote menu for all of the usable emotes, using `chrome.runtime.getURL` usually it supposed to load about 9 emotes on every channel but i made a special case for specific channel that loads in total about 60 of those emotes and that seems to be the problem in my case.

The odd thing is that nothing like that has happened when i was testing my extension in unpacked version

I use `executeScript` in my background script to trigger my JavaScript modules and they work without a problem but once i get on that one url where more emotes are required to load, it seems to finish doing it's job and in chrome://extensions all i can see is  `This extension may have been corrupted.`

For my menu i use `document.createElement` to create 4 divs and 9 or 60 images then `appendChild` to append images into those divs.

I want to say that too many images is what bothers my extension. What would be the best approach to fix it.

Comment: Definitively sounds like a bug in the browser e.g. https://crbug.com/720597. It should have been fixed in Chrome 61.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there any fix for it right now?